# Digit permutation puzzle

Tags: algorithms, permutations, puzzle

Given two numbers a and b , 
Find all the numbers between them such that  :

If x is number between a and b then digits in 2x are permutation of digits in x.

Comment: Why can't you just cycle through all the numbers between a and b and check? What is the desired complexity?

Comment: Cannot loop so much ..  a can be 1 and b can be 10 raised to 18. I wish to get ans in few seconds. Desired complexity is as best as it can get.

Comment: See https://oeis.org/A023086, and in particular see the link to https://blog.plover.com/math/dd.html.

Comment: This is exactly what i was looking for. Can u post the link as ans. I’ll accept it as answer. Thank u so much